# Excel - Finding the biggest total donation in a multi-donation list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I'm trying to achieve is kind of basic, but I couldn't find so far an answer or formula to get this:

I have two columns, "donor" and "donation", and would like to find, using a formula, who is the biggest donator, considering the possibility to receive multiple donations from the same person. So, something like:

| Donor | Donation |
| --- | --- |
| Mat | 10 |
| Ana | 20 |
| Paul | 20 |
| Mat | 12 |
| Ana | 1 |

I know I can easily see this information using a dynamic table, but there is a combination of index, sum and such who show me the name of the biggest donator and how much he has donated? (Mat, 21, not necessarily on the same cell or same format, I can "left", "right" or something like this after getting the answer).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your sample data we see `Ana` and `Paul` has maximum denotation. So, which one do you expect as result? Or do you want to sum then find biggest donor.

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Comment: You could also simply use a pivot table I suppose. It would aggregate these values for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:A6),y,SUMIFS(B2:B6,A2:A6,x),TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(x,y),2,-1),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect @Harun24hr, thank you very much, works like a charm and I learned some new functions :)

For future reference to brazilian portuguese speakers, the formula syntax is:


'= LET(x; ÚNICO(A2:A6);y;SOMASES(B2:B6;A2:A6;x);PEGAR(CLASSIFICAR(HSTACK(x;y);2;-1);1))'